# Where is Customizer related data stored is the database?

Tags: theme-customizer

How would I go about finding if a image (with a certain URL) is used stored in the Customizer data?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Theme mods are stored in the options table, one field per theme. Option name is `theme_mods_themename`, for instance `theme_mods_twentyfifteen`.

Comment: Great. Now then if I want to find the theme mods for a particular theme, then I can query the database for the option_name 'theme_mods_' + <theme name>.

Comment: use this query to spot the them : SELECT * FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE '%theme_mods_%'