# Downloading customized theme from wordpress

Tags: multisite, child-theme

I activated wordpress theme `twenty twenty` and make some changes in it like background color , change default contents and landing pages etc .

Can I export this modified theme and import in another wordpress website so that I dont have to make same changes again and again ?

We have to replicate same content around 40 wordpress websites which we are trying to do it via multisite but problem with multisite is it install default content of a theme and not a modified one.
Can anyone advise me how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want easy solution, install [Download Plugins and Themes from Dashboard](https://wordpress.org/plugins/download-plugins-dashboard/) plugin. Then you will able to download the theme. And you will able to install the theme any site you want.

*Manual way:*

After login to your hosting dashboard like cPanel, navigate to File Manager. Inside www directory, you will get **wp-content** directory, inside that, you will get  **themes** directory. Here you will get all of your themes. You can download your theme from here.

If you can use FTP clients like Filezilla, you navigate to **public_html** or **www** folder. then navigate to **wp-content/themes**. You can download from there.

Comment: I tried with downloading wp-content directory but it dosent contain any modifications I made like color changes and some other customizations.

Answer (score 0):

If you're changing settings using the WP Customizer then those changes are stored in the DB and you'd simply need to locate them, then paste them into the other DBs.

This answer will help you locate them, even has a handy SQL script:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/203227/60844